# Timeline Activities in Microsoft Graph

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-graph-api

I'm checking the Activities API of Windows 10. I am able to insert activities into the graph and I'm getting a confirmation, but when I try to read out the activity it is not there.On Windows I also also no changes what I would expect.

I created an app and I'm logging in with this url: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=MY_ID&scope=openid profile UserActivity.ReadWrite.CreatedByApp&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/auth/callback&state=4711`

After the login I take the code and fetch my bearer token like this:

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id=MY_ID&client_secret=MY_SECRET&grant_type=authorization_code&code=M.R3_BAY.12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789abc&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/auth/callback
```

This works as expected. Then I'm inserting the activity like this:

```
PUT https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/activities/%2Ftest123
Authorization: Bearer MY_BEARER_TOKEN 
Content-type: application/json

{
  "appActivityId": "/test123",
  "activitySourceHost": "https://rks.app",
  "userTimezone": "Europe/Berlin",
  "appDisplayName": "My Test App",
  "activationUrl": "https://rks.app/?active",
  "contentUrl": "https://rks.app/?content",
  "fallbackUrl": "https://rks.app/?fallback",
  "contentInfo": {
    "@context": "https://schema.org",
    "@type": "Article",
    "author": "rekire",
    "name": "Testing all the shit"
  },
  "visualElements": {
    "attribution": {
      "iconUrl": "https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPzx8.png",
      "alternateText": "rekire",
      "addImageQuery": false
    },
    "description": "Description why I am great!",
    "backgroundColor": "#ff0000",
    "displayText": "Displaying that I am great",
    "content": {
      "$schema": "https://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
      "type": "AdaptiveCard",
      "body": [
        {
          "type": "TextBlock",
          "text": "Fancy shit!"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Is there anything wrong with my api calls? When I press <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> I see not that activity it should be there right?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I missed to add a `historyItems` node. Here is an sample:

```
"historyItems": [
  {
    "userTimezone": "Europe/Berlin",
    "startedDateTime": "2020-09-19T16:01:02.123Z",
    "lastActiveDateTime": "2020-09-21T08:04:22.123Z"
  }
]
```